# Happy Numbers doesn't update variable

Tags: python

I've been coding for about 3 months. Could someone help me understand why my code isn't working? I could look up the answer, but I'd really like to figure out what is going wrong. It runs perfectly the first time through the code, but while it is While-Looping, x always stays as the number inserted into the function. Thanks for your help! The assignment and code is below (for an Udemy class).

Happy Numbers -
A happy number is defined by the following process. Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers. Display an example of your output here. Find first 8 happy numbers.

```
def find_happy_number(x):
    
        #we need a bunch of lists
        digit_list = []
        squared_list = []
        result_list = []
        happy_numbers = []
        unhappy_numbers = []
       
        
        while True:
            
            #break our number into digits
            x = str(x)
            for digit in x:
                digit_list.append(int(digit))
            
            #square each digit and store in list
            for digit in digit_list:
                squared_digit = digit**2
                squared_list.append(squared_digit)
            
            #adds all numbers on that list
            result = sum(squared_list)
            
            
            print(result)

            #check to see if it is a happy number
            if result == 1:
                print(f'{x} is a happy number!')
                break
            
            #check to see if it is an un-happy number
            if result in result_list:
                print(f'{x} is an UN-happy number!')
                break
                
            
            #if it isn't we continue the churning.
            #adds result to result list to see if we are looping infinitally
            
            x = result
            result_list.append(result)
`
```

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you are not resetting `digit_list` and `squared_list` in every loop, so they just keep getting bigger and bigger.  Move their initialization into the `while` loop, or use a list comprehension instead of a loop.

Comment: It seems so obvious now!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PROBLEM is that you are not resetting `digit_list` and `squared_list` in every loop, so they just keep getting bigger and bigger. Move their initialization into the while loop, or use a list comprehension instead of a loop.

Consider this for your loop:

```
    while True:
        digit_list = [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]
        squared_list = [digit**2 for digit in digit_list]
```

Now you don't need to initialize them.  Or, for extra fun, combine it all into one:

```
    while True:
        result = sum(int(digit)**2 for digit in str(x))
```

Comment: I'll try these as soon as I have time. That cuts my code down so much!

Comment: You should mention your comment in the question in this answer, since that's the actual answer :)